# Git truncates long path and fails to stat

Tags: git, composer-php

I have weird git error which occurs in a `composer install` call which fails.

I debugged it down and it seems that git has a problem with long pathes and truncates the path after 128 chars.
Then i receive this error

> fatal: failed to stat
> '/home/my/128/chars/long/path/vendor/oxid-esales/oxideshop-unified-namespace-generato':
> No such file or directory

Note that the last character is omitted, it should be `oxideshop-unified-namespace-generator`, it is exactly after 128 chars.

In composer i am declaring custom repositories to use a fork instead of the original package.
This leads to this command within composer:

```
git clone --no-checkout '/home/user/.cache/composer/vcs/https---github.com-oxid-eshop-gpl-oxideshop-unified-namespace-generator.git/' '/home/my/128/chars/long/path/vendor/oxid-esales/oxideshop-unified-namespace-generator' --dissociate --reference '/home/user/.cache/composer/vcs/https---github.com-oxid-eshop-gpl-oxideshop-unified-namespace-generator.git/' &&  cd '/home/my/128/chars/long/path/vendor/oxid-esales/oxideshop-unified-namespace-generator' &&  git remote set-url origin -- 'git@github.com:oxid-eshop-gpl/oxideshop-unified-namespace-generator.git'
```

Which fails at the `git remote set-url origin -- 'git@github.com:oxid-eshop-gpl/oxideshop-unified-namespace-generator.git'` command with:

> fatal: failed to stat
> '/home/my/128/chars/long/path/vendor/oxid-esales/oxideshop-unified-namespace-generato':
> No such file or directory

Why is the path cut off here after 128 chars?

I tried already with: `git config --global core.longpaths true`

But it still fails.
It happens on a linux server.